# Find specific string in files then delete other files with same filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need some help making a bash script.

Okay, so lets say I have these 3 types of files in a system:

```
fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9.desc

fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9.meta

fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9~fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9.alias
```

I need to find a specific "string" in the `.alias` files and if I find it in that `.alias` file I then need to delete the associated `.meta` and `.desc` files with the same filename but they have slightly different filenames with an additional name after `~`.

How would I script this?

I have

```
find . -name "*.alias" -exec grep -l "string" {} \;
```

and it returns

```
./fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9~fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9.alias
```

which is correct, but now I need it to only return `fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9`, then delete all the files with filename `fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9` regardless of file extension including the `.alias` file.

That's as far as I got.

Comment: please provide a sample input and output which will make it easy to write the script

Comment: output would be the associated files deleted and input would be basically any string I want to find in the .alias files

Comment: Start with `for file in $(grep -l "string" *.alias)`. For each file, remove everything after `~` to get a prefix, then use `rm $prefix.*`.

Comment: See the bash [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section to find out how to remove everything after `~` from a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all especially @Barmar. I got it to work with

```
for file in $(grep -l "string" *.alias)
do 
    prefix=${file%%~*}
    rm $prefix*.*
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> Script:

```
  filename=fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9~fe516148-3e8b-4816-8481-6fd079a46ae9.alias
    string=abcd
    if [ "$(grep $string $filename)" -lt 1 ]
    then
        f1=$(echo $filename | cut -d'~' -f1)
        rm -f $f1.desc
        rm -f $f1.meta
    fi
```

This is the script based on the description where string is grepped in the file and if found, then file name is cut from the .alias file and those files are deleted.

Hope this helps.